# What is Dreamweaver's last version with jQuery and full JS support?

Tags: javascript, oop, autocomplete, dreamweaver

I have Dreamweaver CS 5.5 version 11.0 Built 4909.

But it's not the latest version. It doesn't recognize jQuery, do not offers hints to it. Also it doesn’t know anything about inheritance in JS. It cannot see methods/properties of parent function from the descendant function. When I test code with the browser all parent methods work from descendant. But when I write code it only sees local methods/properties and cannot give any hint on the parent’s methods. Is it standard behavior of Dreamweaver or I just have old version of it? On Adobe site there is written that new DW sees jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dreamweaver 11.6 is last version.

Also, if javascript autocompletion is important to you, I recomment JetBrains WebStorm, this IDE have a best javascript support today, it can process even js files included from remote sources.

Answer (score 1):

You can check jQuery code hinting under "Edit" menu, "Preferences..." then select the "Code Hints" option on the preference list.  You should see one for jQuery which you will need to ensure is ticked.